# Allow all/most plain printable Unicode characters in Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unicode

I have a Node.JS application which currently does not allow Unicode characters in filenames. I'd like to go ahead and start allowing certain characters. For example `Café` or `你好` would be allowed as filenames.

However, I know that `NUL` character attacks are possible, and there are potentially bothersome control characters. Really all control characters (and most most non-printable characters) should be blocked.

To start with, I was planning to obtain some of the ranges of 'safe' unicode characters and code them in manually. However, is there a quicker way? Perhaps all the file-system safe ranges are already listed somewhere I can easily obtain?

Comment: One option would be to use a regex engine that supports unicode properties (like https://www.npmjs.com/package/xregexp) and match the filenames against `[\p{Letter}\p{Number}]`